# UIView frame more than 5000X5000 is not calling drawrect method

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, zooming

Is there any limitations for UIView size in iOS? As i'm working with infinite zooming of a drawing view, i'm facing the drawing issue if more zooming view size more than 5000 pixels. Is there any way to achieve infinite zooming?

Here is my code block:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.scrView.maximumZoomScale=2.0;
    self.scrView.minimumZoomScale=0.05;
    self.objDrawingView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrView.frame.size.width*10, self.scrView.frame.size.height*10);
    self.scrView.contentSize=self.objDrawingView.frame.size;
    self.scrView.zoomScale=0.1;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale
    {
        [self.objDrawingView.layer setContentsScale:self.objDrawingView.transform.a*[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];
        [self.objDrawingView setNeedsDisplay];
    }
```

Comment: Big `UIView` is bad option for infinite zooming, because UIView is finite by default. You should handle pinch gesture by yourself and draw different content on simple view depending on zoom.

Comment: @Ossir then it is stretching if i zoom out.

Comment: are we talking about a bitmap which would request `100MB` of the system memory? you are so lucky, your app could be terminated easily by iOS as bad memory citizen. if you want to develop a game that is not how you can represent big maps or huge platforms.